# how pass dom element value to ajax request (html.Pagedlist parameters)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am learning ajax requests and I was wondering if I am doing right here. Well I have a page which include pagination, sorting and searching. I am trying to get this by ajax because I don't want to load the whole page again. so this is part of my parent view :
.

```
..
<div id="nursesList">
               @Html.Partial("PaginatedNurses", Model)
</div>
...
```

And this is my partial which I try to use ajax:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http
@using X.PagedList
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.Common
@model X.PagedList.IPagedList<Services.ViewModel.Admin.Nurse.NurseDetailsViewModel>
    <form>
    <div id="RegisteredNurses">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                از سن <input class="form-control" id="minAge" type="number" name="MinAge" value="@ViewBag.MinAge" />

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                تا سن <input class="form-control" id="maxAge" type="number" name="maxAge" value="@ViewBag.MaxAge" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                مرتب سازی بر اساس
                <select class="form-control" name="SortOrder" value="@ViewBag.SortOrder" style="width: 200px" id="sortOrder">
                    <option value="age">
                        سن
                    </option>
                    <option value="registerDate">
                        زمان ثبت نام
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                نحوه مرتب سازی
                <select class="form-control" name="SortType" value="@ViewBag.SortType" style="width: 200px" id="sortType">
                    <option value=1>
                        صعودی
                    </option>
                    <option value=0>
                        نزولی
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="جست و جو" id="btnSearch" />
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="table-extended-transactions" class="table mb-0">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>نام</th>
                    <th>سن</th>
                    <th>شماره پروانه کار</th>
                    @*<th>شماره ملی</th>*@
                    <th>دوره حرفه ای</th>
                    <th>تاریخ ثبت نام</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach (var nurse in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><i class="bx bxs-circle success font-small-1 mr-50 align-middle"></i><span>@nurse.FullName</span></td>
                        <td class="text-bold-700">@nurse.Age</td>
                        <td class="text-bold-700">@nurse.NurseSystemNumber</td>
                        <td>
                            @nurse.ProfessionalCourseDescription
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @nurse.SubmissionDatePersian
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <span class="bx bx-dots-horizontal-rounded font-medium-3 dropdown-toggle nav-hide-arrow cursor-pointer" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="menu">
                                </span>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("NurseDetails", "Admin", new {id = @nurse.Id})"><i class="bx bx-edit-alt mr-1"></i> نمایش جزئیات</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="setInvitation('@nurse.Id')">تایید</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="refuseRegister('@nurse.Id')"><i class="bx bx-trash mr-1"></i>عدم تایید</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div id="pager">
                @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("RegisteredNurseList", new { page}),
                    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "RegisteredNurses" }))
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </form>
        @section modalSection
        {
            <script src="~/js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
        }
```

Main part is here:

```
<div id="pager">
                @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("RegisteredNurseList", new { page}),
                    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "RegisteredNurses" }))
            </div>
```

I want to add the value of inputs in my dom. For example:

```
<div id="pager">
                @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("RegisteredNurseList", new { page , sortOrder=('#sortOrder').val()}), 
                    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "RegisteredNurses" }))
            </div>
```

I know this `sortOrder=('#sortOrder').val()` is not a valid code, but I want to find an alternative for this or even any better approach.
This is my controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RegisteredNurseList(int? page, int? sortType,string sortOrder,
            int? minAge, int? maxAge)
        {
            bool isAjax = HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
            int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            int pageSize = 2;
            int skip = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
           
            ViewBag.MinAge = minAge ?? 18;
            ViewBag.MaxAge = maxAge ?? 99;
            ViewBag.sortType = sortType ?? 1;
            ViewBag.SortOrder = sortOrder;
           
            
            var tuple = await _admin.GetNurses(skip, pageSize, sortOrder, sortType ?? 1, minAge ?? 18, maxAge ?? 99);
            int total = tuple.Item2;
            var nurses = tuple.Item1;
            var result = new StaticPagedList<NurseDetailsViewModel>(nurses, pageNumber, pageSize, total);
            
            
            if (isAjax)
            {
                return (ActionResult) PartialView("PaginatedNurses", result);
            }
            return View(result);
            
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer here will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50727347/177416

You want to capture the user's clicking of a page number in the pager control and rewrite the link before letting it through. This is done on the client via JavaScript `onClick` handler on the page numbers; the following handler goes in your jQuery document ready event handler:

```
$('#pager').find('a[href]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = this.split('?')[0]
        + "?page=" + getQueryStringValue(this, 0).replace('page=','') 
        + "&sortOrder=" + $("#sortOrder").val(); // Add other values if needed
    }
});
```

Here's the helper function:

```
getQueryStringValue: function (anchor, index) {
    var queryString = $(anchor).attr('href').split('?')[1];
    var values = queryString.split('&');
    return values[index];
}
```

This line gets us the raw URL [without the querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5817548/177416); `this` in this case is the URI:

```
this.split('?')[0]
```

Setting `location.href` is like clicking a link; it'll [redirect the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16425288/177416) to the indicated URI.

Comment: thanks dude I already have gotten you idea in that question which you mention to it.